# Error al compilar aplicacion de android

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, compilar

Me esta dando un error que no entiendo al intentar compilar esta aplicación creada con flutter para android, os dejo por aqui el mensaje de error.

La aplicacion se ejecuta bien sin problema y es mas la instale en modo realise pero no me funciona he probado a cambiar las rutas del SDK pero no sirve de nada cada vez que ejecuto el comando se pierde lo que cambie y se sobre escribe.

```
C:\Users\JOMAN\AndroidStudioProjects\jugueteriasnikki>flutter build apk
Initializing gradle...                                              1,0s
Resolving dependencies...                                          13,0s

Compiler message:
Error: SDK root directory not found: file:///C:/Users/JOMAN/SDK%20flutter/flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk_product/.
Error: Error when reading 'file:///C:/Users/JOMAN/SDK%20flutter/flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk_product/platform_strong.dill': El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.

Error: Error when reading 'file:///C:/Users/JOMAN/SDK%20flutter/flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk_product/platform_strong.dill': El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
.
.
.
Compiler terminated unexpectedly.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       8,9s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Las rutas del SDK deben ir especificadas en las variables de ambiente en la variable `path`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en este caso el problema principal se debe a dos posibles causas:

- No existe el path del SDK.
- El path del SDK contiene un espacio.

En este caso es seguramente la segunda causa,

> Error: SDK root directory not found:
>   file:///C:/Users/JOMAN/SDK%20flutter/flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk_product/.

te sugiero cambiar el folder `/SDK flutter/` a un nombre que no contenga espacio, por ejemplo:

```
/SDK_flutter/
```

Comment: Gracias compañero lo probare a ver pero una cosa que me extrana es el local.propieties de android se cambia solo el flutter.sdk por que es?

Comment: en el local.properties se tiene el ndk.dir y sdk.dir , si instalas flutter se agrega flutter.sdk=

Comment: he cambiado la ruta del SDK de flutter ahora esta en C:\flutter lo cambie en los ajustes del proyecto, pero me sigue apareciendo la ruta en el local.porperties de: "flutter.sdk=C:\\Users\\JOMAN\\SDK flutter\\flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable\\flutter" se la cambio pero se vuelve a poner la misma automáticamente al hacer el flutter build apk, aparte me aparece un error en "C:\\" que me dice que ha de ser "C\:\\" lo cambio pero se vuelve a modificar solo mal

Comment: @Elenays he echo lo que me dijiste pero no sirve de nada me sigue dando el mismo error en la terminal al compilarlo

Comment: Luego de los cambios sugeridos de Elenasys, puedes probar de crear un nuevo proyecto de cero e intentar el build para descartar problemas de configuración en tu proyecto? De esta forma puedes descartar si es la configuración donde debes seguir buscando o dentro del proyecto. Espero te ayude, saludos.